# Сглаживаются пиксели в PictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

Во время вывода картинки маленького размера в `PictureBox` возникла проблема. Пиксели отображаются не четко( желаемый резльтат ), а сглажено. Создаю `Bitmap`, затем копирую его в более большой. Результата нет. Как это исправить?

```
Bitmap Pic1 = new Bitmap(160, 90);
Bitmap Pic2 = new Bitmap(Pic, new Size(picturebox1.Height, picturebox1.Wight));
picturebox1.Image = Pic2;
```

Comment: Покажите код, как именно копируете?

Comment: Пример кода и картинки сможете показать? Без этого не совсем понятно в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя лит написать размеры картинки и picturebox?

Из вопроса непонятно.: вы уменьшаете картинку или увеличиваете?

Если уменьшаете - можно делать это с использованием того или иного метода ресайза, подробнее - [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/243285/)

Пиксели при этом всё равно поплывут, но это будет не так заметно.

Если увеличиваете - а чего тогда вы ожидаете? Что комп дорисует пиксели, чтобы картинка оставалась четкой? Есть простой способ - увеличивать в кратное количество раз, напрмиер 48x64 в 96x128

Comment: Размер picturebox - на весь экран, размер картинки - 160 х 90

Answer (score 1):

Можно отрисовать изображение с качеством `HighQualityBicubic`. Это даст несколько лучший результат.

```
var pic2 = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);

using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(pic2))
{
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.DrawImage(pic1, 0, 0, pic2.Width, pic2.Height);
}

pictureBox1.Image = pic2;
```

Но всё равно сильно увеличенное изображение будет мутным.
Здесь `pic1` - оригинальное изображение.

---

Кстати, `PictureBox` имеет свойство `SizeMode`. Достаточно задать ему значение `Zoom` и можно обойтись без ручного создания увеличенного изображения. То есть `pic2` создавать не нужно.

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
pictureBox1.Image = pic1;
```

Результат будет такой же, как в вашем изначальном варианте.

---

Чтобы добиться лучшего результата, нужно использовать какие-либо внешние библиотеки для работы с растровой графикой.

Идеальным вариантом будет использование векторной графики. Её можно растягивать и сжимать как угодно без потери качества.

Comment: Я знаю про SizeMode. Но изображение все равно мутное. Буду использовать сторонние библиотеки. Но какую выбрать: нужна простая и установленная вместе с системой (чтобы вместе с программой не нужно было ее устанавливать - может что-то есть в Win32?) или популярная, которую устанавливают часто (например DirectX, которая нужна для многих игр). Можете что-то посоветовать?

Comment: @GREATDNG - Ничего предустановленного нет. С учётом того, что вы крохотную картинку 160*90 растягиваете на весь экран, помочь может только искусственный интеллект. Или софт наподобие deep fake: вводите туда свою картинку, на выходе получаете... Emma Watson с конями...